# file association saving not working on Opensuse 13.1

Tags: linux, kde, opensuse, mime-types, plasma-tv

I'm on Opensuse (KDE5). For some unknown reason it's impossible to change what application should be used to open a specific file. Even if I do apply or save, after I go in the same menu, it gets the old settings. Now for instance, when I want to open a folder ark is invoked instead of dolphin...
Do you know which file is modified by KDE? I'm thinking to manually editing that file.

Cheers

Comment: openSUSE 13.1 is an outdated release that doesn't receive support anymore; you should update to a more recent release, the current version is 42.2, or you can opt for the rolling version Tumbleweed.

Comment: I was wrong, the problem is on Opensuse 42.1